# How to set the values from the ajax to the table in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am having one JSP with a table,and in that I have two columns called status and numRecords.
I am getting new status and numrecords values thru ajax.
what I want to is replace status and  numrecords of the table with the newly retrieved values on ajax.
I have tried like this,this is my jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>File Upload</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/button.css" />
        <link href="css/common-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
        <style>
        a{
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
        </style>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        var id;
         function refreshRecord(value)
        {
            id = value;
            alert(id);
        }
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#refresh").click(function(){
               var fileId=id;
               alert("ajax id is "+fileId);
               $.ajax({
               type:'post',
                url:'checkStatusAndNumRecs',
               data:{fileId:fileId},
                success:function(data)
               {
                    var obj=data.split(':');
                    alert("status is :"+obj[0]);
                   $("#stat").html(obj[0]);
                   $("#recs").html(obj[1]);
               },
               error:function(data)
            {
                $("#div1").html("It was a failure !!!");
            }
                });
                });
                });
        </script>    
        </head>
    <body>
    <%@include file="index1.html" %>
    <div class="box2">    
     <div class="box3"> 
    <s:property value="userId"/>
    </div>  
        <center><h2>FILE STATUS</h2></center>
    <center> 
     
        <form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="myFile" class="text">Upload your file:</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="upload"/>
            <input type="file" name="myFile" size="40"  class="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Refresh" class="button"/>   
        </form>
        </center>        
          
          <center>
         <table border="1" class="displaytab" id="rtable">
         <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
         <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;"><center>Admin</center></td></tr>
         </s:if>
         <tr> 
         <th>FileId</th><th>File Name</th><th>Upload Date</th><th>#Records</th><th>Status</th><th>Estimated Time</th><th>Processed Records</th><th>Generate Report</th><th></th><s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}"><th>Controls</th></s:if>
         </tr>
         
         <s:iterator value="uploadList" var="m"> 
            <tr>   
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" /></td> 
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileName}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.uploadDate}" /></td>
            <td id="recs"><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td id="stat"><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></td>
            <td>tbd</td>
            
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report"></a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" id="refresh" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" />);"></a></td>
            <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
                 <td><a href=""><img src="images/details.png"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/plus.png" title="Add Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/minus.png" title="Remove Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/download.png" title="Download"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/reconnect.png" title="Reconnect"></a></td>
                 
            </s:if>
            </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </table>
         </center>
             
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>  
         <center>
         <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
         
<!--          <select name="user names">
            <s:iterator value="userNamesList">
                <option value="emailColumn" > <s:property/>
                </option>
            </s:iterator>
        </select> -->
        
         <table border="1" class="displaytab" id="usertab">
         <s:if test="%{uploadListMap.size() != 0}">   
         <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">User Job Details</center></td></tr>
         <tr> 
         <th>FileId</th><th>File Name</th><th>Upload Date</th><th>#Records</th><th>Status</th><th>Estimated Time</th><th>Processed Records</th><th>Generate Report</th><th></th><s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}"><th>Controls</th></s:if>
         </tr>
         <s:iterator  value="%{uploadListMap}">
         <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;"><center><s:property value="key"/></center></td>
         <s:iterator value="value" var="u">
         <tr>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.fileId}" /></td> 
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.fileName}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.uploadDate}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#u.status}" /></td>
            <td>tbd</td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report"></a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" id="refresh" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#u.fileId}" />);"></a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/details.png"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/plus.png" title="Add Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/minus.png" title="Remove Instance"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/download.png" title="Download"></a>
                 <a href=""><img src="images/reconnect.png" title="Reconnect"></a></td>
         </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </s:if>
         </table>
         </s:if>
         </center> 
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is JSON returned by the server?

Comment: @RomanC its not JSON its a string like this -> new:8,i am splitting it into obj[0] and obj[1].

Comment: You should return JSON to access the obj[0] and obj[1].

Comment: json is compulsarily required,but i am able to alert obj[0] and obj[1].

Comment: @RomanC how i can use JSON.

Comment: You can use it directly in javascript. But I think you didn't get JSON in the `data` variable. If you did what is `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`?

Comment: @RomanC if i get JSON in data,next how to parse it to obj[0] and obj[1]

Comment: Did I ask you to *parse* it? JSON objects don't need to parse. I need to know a structure of JSON to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

If your action returns JSON object like `{"status":"success","records":"123"}` then to set the values you could use

```
success:function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  $("#stat").val(data.status);
  $("#recs").val(data.records);
}
```

Comment: thanx,i want to create different ids for <td> of status column in the jsp i have provided,using for loop id's like status1,status2,status3...for each iteration of list.how can i generate those values using forloop,and how can i put that id inside td tag..

Comment: you can use `%{'status'+#status.index}` for ids.

Comment: dint got can u little bit elaborate with for loop.<td id="stat"><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></td>
for this i want to generate different ids usinf forloop,for each list this td is iterating.

Comment: `<td id="<s:property value="%{'status'+#status.index}" />"></td>` this will get you different ids

Comment: what is that index,what it will give?

Comment: it's the value of the index of the current element of the iterator (0,1,...size())